# Split a file into parts based on the data using Python

Tags: python, file, split, eval

I am looking for the Python equivalent of an awk script to split a file into 26 parts based on a flag in the record. This is because there are 26 different record types in one file, a hangover from hierarchical databases used by Burroughs in the 1970s. I expected to be able to open 26 files named f_A to f_Z instead of the traditional f1 and then stream out the records as I read them in without holding the whole lot in a buffer.

```
# Gawk original - split new valuation roll format into record types A-Z
# run gawk -F\| -f split.awk input_file
# creates A.raw, B.raw, .... Z.raw
# Oct 1995 
{ident = $8; 
file = ident".raw";
print $0 >> file}
```

So I thought I could make up a file handle and then call that with eval() or something to direct each record to the correct output.

```
for line in fileinput.input(src):
    parts = line.split('|')
    recType = parts[7]
    recFile = 'f_'+recType
    if not recType in openFiles:
        eval(recFile) = open(recType+".raw",'w') # how should this line be written?
    eval(recFile).write(line)
    # ....
```

I can get the name of the system file from f1.name
and evaluate a variable to get the handle eg eval("f_A")
but I cannot see how to open the file with a handle that is not hardcoded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`eval` is something to be avoided and, fortunately, it is almost never needed.  In this case, `open(recType+".raw",'w')` creates a file handle.  You just need to associate it with recType.  This is what dictionaries are for.

In the code below, `openFiles` is a dictionary.  Every time that we encounter a new `recType`, we open a file for it and save its filehandle in `openFiles` under the key `recType`.  Whenever we want to write to that file again, we just ask the dictionary for the file handle.  Thus:

```
openFiles = {}
for line in fileinput.input(src):
    parts = line.split('|')
    recType = parts[7]
    if not recType in openFiles:
        openFiles[recType] = open('f_' + recType, 'w')
    openFiles[recType].write(line)
    # ....
```

Comment: Please include some explanation to be more educative.

Comment: @LaszloPapp OK.  I hope that it is more educational now.